Resizing Circular Queues?
I'm currently working on implementing circular queues, and I've encountered an issue when it comes to resizing the queue. I've successfully implemented a resize function for linear (array) based queues.
Here's the function I currently use for resizing linear queues:
template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::Grow() {
    const uint32_t newSize = m_size + 1;
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < static_cast<int>(m_size); i++)
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    delete[] array;
    m_size = newSize;
    array = newArray;
}

However, applying the same principle to circular queues seems to defeat the purpose of using a circular structure.
Could someone provide insights or an implementation example on how to resize circular queues?
Thank you in advance for your help!

You don't need to reinvent the wheel. For both cases just use std::vector it's safer and easier. Don't jump onto pointers as the first solution; in C++ raw pointer is is one-past-the-end solution.

It depends on the semantics you want for the resizing of the circular queue. For example you can decide that after resize the Q elements start at index 0 (i.e. shift the content to the beginning). Also I agree with the comment above: you should use std::vector.

@Red.Wave I know that but I'm student and I have to implement all those myself without using vector etc.

T* newArray = new T[newSize] this is not needed use std::vector as said. This will take care of memory managment and copying (moving) of the data. Side note : no need to do the static_cast thing either. In cases like this there is also std::copy or just make your index of type std::size_t

@wohlstad  I know that but I'm student and I have to implement all those myself without using vector

@M_T the suggestion to use a std::vector was only related to replacing the raw C array. But in any case you need to define what should happen when a circular queue is resized as I noted above.

@M_T Then be smart and write a small vector like class yourself and reuse that in your Queue implementation. That way you can test it first AND you will get extra points from us and maybe even from your professor.

Just remember datastructure classes don't learn you how to use C++ as it should be used. So be prepare yourself to use std::vector and std::queue etc in the future :)

Since you are a student, pointers are mother of evil. If you need to manipulate them, learn resource management first: ownership, RAII, rule 350 and copy+swap idiom(for beginners). Without proper understanding of the above - one way or another - you will get trapped in common memory management issues(leak, use-after-free, double-free, dangling). Resource management is not part of academic instructions(they're blind in that regard). Use std::vector as prime implementation, then create your own providing the part of std::vector interface that is essential to your task. Apply rule 3.

As comments have already indicated, in C++ you would better stay away from C-style arrays and use std::vector, but to answer your question: to implement this for a circular queue, you could copy the used section of the array to the start of the new array, applying a shift that corresponds to where the front/rear of your circular queue are located. Then set the front/rear fields to the shifted result. Depending on what you call front or rear, front would get 0 as index in the new setup, and the rear would be determined by the used size of the queue.
Something like this (but it depends on how you define and use front/rear concepts in your implementation):
template <typename T>
void Queue<T>::Grow() {
    const uint32_t newSize = m_size + 1;
    T* newArray = new T[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
        newArray[i] = array[(m_front + i) % m_size];
    delete[] array;
    m_size = newSize;
    m_front = 0;
    m_rear = (m_rear + m_size - m_front) % m_size; 
    array = newArray;
}

You'll need to adapt this to fit your class and front/rear concepts. Also you might need to use newSize instead of m_size in the last expression. Again this depends on how you maintain state for the front/rear of your circular queue.
